# Is this short program legal C++?

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing

while solving a test on http://cppquiz.org I found this interesting piece of code :

```
#include <iostream>

int f(int& a, int& b) {
    a = 3;
    b = 4;
    return a + b;
}

int main () {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = f(a, a);// note a,a
    std::cout << a << b << c;
}
```

My question is this program legal C++ or it isnt? Im concerned about strict aliasing.

Comment: Have you tried running it? (I'm really not sure what you think is illegal- the fact that you pass the same argument twice to a function?)

Comment: Yes, it's legal. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: AFAIK, it's legal; it isn't sensible, but it is legal.

Comment: My guess is that it's legal (most things are), but I couldn't tell you what it will output, the compiler could rearrange those statements.

Comment: The output is pretty easy to predict and shouldn't be subject to the whims of the compiler.

Comment: what about this? `a = ++b;` would this be ok too?

Comment: @user2280716: In the function?  No, that's undefined behavior, when `a` and `b` reference the same variable.

Comment: Please see [What is the strict aliasing rule?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Comment: Strict aliasing is about types not variables.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley yep that's what I thought. But this is interesting.

Comment: @gongzhitaao, that's regarding C and there you have a keyword for it (`restrict`). How does that apply to references in C++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mention strict aliasing – but [strict aliasing is concerned with aliases of different types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/1968). It doesn’t apply here.

There’s no rule that forbids this code. It’s the moral equivalent of the following code:

```
int x = 42;
int& y = x;
int& z = x;
```

Or, more relevantly, it’s equivalent to having several child nodes refer to the same parent node in a tree data structure.

Comment: nice example with a tree. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is legal.

I could formally *prove* it only by quoting the majority of the C++ standard text.

You are passing two references, both of which happen to refer to the same object, which is perfectly fine. You then assign new values to that single object, in turn. Also fine.

Comment: No, there *is* aliasing involved. A reference (actually, a pointer) is an alias.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: You lost me at "a reference (actually, a pointer)". There are no pointers here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Further, I cannot find anything in the standard that refers to either references or pointers as an "alias". Please assist me in my search.

Comment: Aliases concern a different level of abstraction than pointers and references: on the syntax level aliases don’t exist but they do underly the semantics – and they matter on the same level where the compiler has to decide whether to implement a reference as a pointer or whether it can reuse the same variable.

Comment: So, basically, you just made it up...

Comment: Nonsense. Let’s discuss this in the C++ lounge.